# Is it possible to create an object that has a generic attached to it that is an extension of an abstract class?

Tags: java, swing, generics, abstract

I'm making an abstract class (let's call it Screen) that is an extension of JPanel. I want in the future for users/myself to be able to extend from it. That part isn't the issue.

I'm also trying to make a class (let's call this one "ScratchDrawingProject") that is an extension of JFrame, and it has a generic attached to it. This class also has an instance of the abstract class mentioned above as a screen to be added to it.

I want for the user, in the project's main method (inside some other random file that they create), to be able to create an instance of ScratchDrawingProject with the generic being an extension of Screen. In ScratchDrawingProject's constructor, I want it's Screen variable to be instantiated as a new object of the extension of Screen that the user passes in.

So far for Screen I have:

```
public abstract class Screen extends JPanel{

    private JFrame parent;
    private Graphics2D GRAPHICS;

    //CONSTRUCTOR
    public Screen(JFrame parent){
        this.parent = parent;
        parent.add(this);
        setBounds([bounds]);
        repaint();
    }

    //basically the stuff you would put in the extension's constructor, but this method
    //can be created by an IDE like Eclipse 
    public abstract void start();      

    //basically the paintComponent() for the extension, but in disguise for ease of
    //use of newcomers that aren't *too* knowledgeable of Java.
    public abstract void drawMethod(); 

    //repaint() in disguise
    public void draw(){
        repaint();
    }        

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        GRAPHICS = (Graphics2D) g;
        draw();
    }

    //...methods that extensions of this class can put in their "drawMethod" definition
    //that call GRAPHICS.*, so that the user never even has to see the word Graphics
    //as they are creating their extension...

}
```

So far for ScratchDrawingProject I have:

```
public class ScratchDrawingProject<ScreenType> extends JFrame{

    private Screen screen;

    public ScratchDrawingProject(){
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds([bounds]);
        setVisible(true);
        screen = (ScreenType)new Object(); //which gives me a runtime error because I can't
        screen.setParent(this);            //cast Object to Screen, and I can't make
        screen.start();                    //screen a new ScreenType() because that
    }                                      //gives me a compiling error saying 
                                           //ScreenType can't be instantiated.
}
```

I've also tried doing something I thought was most likely going to be so stupid it was going to give me a compiling error, and that was:

```
public class ScratchDrawingProject<ScreenType extends Screen> extends JFrame{
```

Never would've guessed that wouldn't get me a compiling error purely because of how ridiculous it seemed in concept. Instead, I just got an error again when it came to instantiating screen, whether I tried

```
screen = new ScreenType();
```

which still tells me ScreenType cannot be instantiated, or

```
screen = (ScreenType)new Screen();
```

which tells me Screen can't be instantiated (which I understand is because it's abstract)

---

So in conclusion! My goal is for people to be able to make their own class

```
public class Whatever{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ScratchDrawingProject<IDKScreen> screen = new ScratchDrawingProject<IDKScreen>();
    }
}
```

and

```
public class IDKScreen extends Screen{

    start(){
        //do stuff!
    }

    drawMethod(){
        //do more stuff!
    }
}
```

and have Whatever automatically create a ScratchDrawingProject, create an instance of IDKScreen, add it, call IDKScreen.repaint() to instantiate GRAPHICS for future use, and then finally call IDKScreen's start() and do whatever the user puts in there.

Comment: Please get rid of all the code that is irrelevant to your question.

Comment: Sounds like a very convoluted question when all you probably want is dependency injection.

Comment: `private Graphics2D GRAPHICS;` <- is a bad idea and you should NEVER maintain a reference to a `Graphics` context you did not create

Comment: `public class ScratchDrawingProject<ScreenType> extends JFrame{` should that be `public class ScratchDrawingProject<Screen> extends JFrame{`?  What's `ScreenType`? What's it's relevance?

Comment: @MadProgrammer that's the generic type that would be the extension of Screen the user is creating.

Comment: Then it's irrelevant, your case class is expecting an instance of an object which extends from `Screen`

Comment: @MadProgrammer Screen was the first thing I tried putting for the generic name, but that didn't help my case either. Honestly, I'd learned about generics a while back in a college course for Java, but this is my first time actually trying to use them in something of my own creation.

Comment: Why doesn't using `Screen` help you?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I still can't instantiate an object of type Screen because it's abstract.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Never heard of it, so I'll look into that now.

Comment: @JereTheJuggler Yeah, sorry, my dad, it should be `<S extends Screen>` :P

Answer (score 2):

So, first off, you seem to lack an understand into how Swing painting works. I'd suggest having a closer look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/), as you seem to be violating some very important concepts.

Starting with you abstract `Screen`...

```
public abstract class Screen extends JPanel{

    // Bad idea
    //private Graphics2D GRAPHICS;

    //CONSTRUCTOR
    public Screen(){
        // Generally a bad idea, use getPreferredSize instead
        //setBounds([bounds]);
        // Pointless, you're not displayable yet
        //repaint();
    }

    //basically the stuff you would put in the extension's constructor, but this method
    //can be created by an IDE like Eclipse 
    public abstract void start();      

    //basically the paintComponent() for the extension, but in disguise for ease of
    //use of newcomers that aren't *too* knowledgeable of Java.
    //public abstract void drawMethod(); 
    // Which based on what you seem to be trying to do, you would be one

    //repaint() in disguise
    public void draw(){
        repaint();
    }        

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        // Some painting stuff...
        performPaint(g2d);
        g2d.dispose();
        // This is probably among the worse things you can do, simply put
        // don't change or modify the state of a component from which in paint
        // method which might, directly or indirectly, trigger a repaint,
        // you're just asking for trouble
        //draw();
    }

    // Basically, this gets called when the component needs to be repainted
    protected abstract void performPaint(Graphics2D g2d);

    //...methods that extensions of this class can put in their "drawMethod" definition
    //that call GRAPHICS.*, so that the user never even has to see the word Graphics
    //as they are creating their extension...

}
```

Next, you need to define the requirements for your `ScratchDrawingProject` class...

```
public class ScratchDrawingProject<S extends Screen> extends JFrame{

    private S screen;

    public ScratchDrawingProject(S screen){
            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            this.screen = screen;
            add(screen);
            pack();
            setVisible(true);
            screen.start();                    
    }                                      

    public S getScreen() {
        return screen;
    }

}
```

Basically this just says that `S` must be an instance of class which extends `Screen`

Now, we can define our implementation of `Screen`...

```
public class MyAwesomeScreen extends Screen {

    @Override
    public void start() {
        // Broom
    }

    @Override
    protected void performPaint(Graphics2D g2d) {
        // paint me a rainbow
    }
}
```

And then create an instance of `ScratchDrawingProject` for our implementation...

```
MyAwesomeScreen myAwesomeScreen = new MyAwesomeScreen();
ScratchDrawingProject<MyAwesomeScreen> myScratchDrawingProject = new ScratchDrawingProject<>(myAwesomeScreen);
```

The question then becomes why?  `myScratchDrawingProject` doesn't seem to care about the implementation of `Screen`, only that it's an instance of `Screen`, but that's just an out-of-context observation

Comment: First off, appreciate the effort. When I meant "newcomers", I meant people even less knowledgeable than me (not saying I'm really particularly knowledgeable myself, as you stated). And for your question why, I'm trying to make a system that is analogous to part of a much simpler coding language on a website called Scratch.mit.edu, so that people from there could possibly make/convert a certain type of project from Scratch in a Java environment with about as much ease as possible. An example of the type of project I'm referring to is https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/23096797/, which I created.

Comment: My point been, does `ScratchDrawingProject` really care what type of `Screen` it is?  It's only ever going to be able to interact with the functionality which is exposed by `Screen` anyway

Comment: No, it doesn't. My only goal with ScratchDrawingProject was so the user that is making the extension of screen wouldn't have to do anything regarding making a JFrame or JPanel or anything swing related (or at least, they would without realizing it). All they would have to do is define start() and drawMethod(), and change the generic when they instantiate ScratchDrawingProject to whatever they name their extension of Screen.

Comment: Okay, so my point is, why does `ScratchDrawingProject` need to have any generics at all?

Comment: MadProgrammer is right .. if you have an idea to  override methods of ScratchDrawingProject .. like screen you can change the  convert the type of extended for example  if you have UILoginScreen   ScratchDrawingProject will handle it too.. so why generic ? .. just use Screen class ..